# Next row value without Window functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of page statuses updates. Every row is a status change:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`country`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO t1        (page_id, country, status, date) 
VALUES                (1, 'de', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:11' ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'activated', '2018-09-28 14:54:18' ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:60:12' ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'moderated', '2018-09-28 14:54:12' ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:01' ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'activated', '2018-09-28 14:52:07' ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:11' )
```

I want to see the table in such a format, so that every row shows since when till when a page had a particular status:

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`country`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;



INSERT INTO t2        (page_id, country, status, date_from, date_to) 
VALUES                (1, 'de', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:11', '2018-09-28 14:54:12'  ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'moderated', '2018-09-28 14:54:12', '2018-09-28 14:54:18'  ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'activated', '2018-09-28 14:54:18','2018-09-28 14:60:12'  ) ,
                      (1, 'de', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:60:12','2018-01-25 14:60:12' ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:01','2018-09-28 14:52:07'  ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'activated', '2018-09-28 14:52:07', '2018-09-28 14:52:11' ) ,
                      (2, 'es', 'deactivated', '2018-09-28 14:52:11','2018-01-25 14:52:11'  ) ;
```

The problem is that we are still using MySQL 5.7 and haven't upgraded to mysql8 with cte and window functions, which would easily solve the problem:

```
  SELECT
         country,
         page_id,
         status,
         date as date_from,
        COALESCE(MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY country, page_id ORDER BY date DESC
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
                        TIMESTAMPADD(day, 1, current_timestamp())) as date_to
  FROM t1 ;
```

I assume there should be a trick with self join but can't figure out how exactly!

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the create table statements, and instead show us sample input data and the desired output.

Comment: I really think create table and insert are really useful to 'reproduce' the issue, so please leve them there

Comment: Input and output samples are present along with the create statements.. Creates should be of a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would normally use `LEAD()` for this, rather than your complicated expression.

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select tt1.date
        from t1 tt1
        where tt1.country = t1.country and tt1.page_id = t1.page_id and
              tt1.date > t1.date 
        order by tt1.date asc
        limit 1
       ) as date_to
from t1;
```

This uses `NULL` for the `date_to` values at the end of each sequence.  That makes more sense to me.

If you want to repeat the `date_from` instead (which I don't recommend), then you can do:

```
select t1.*,
       (select min(tt1.date_from, t1.date_from)
        from t1 tt1
        where tt1.page_id = t1.page_id and
              tt1.date_from > t1.date_from
       ) as date_to
from t1;
```

Comment: Sorting of the subquery should be asc to give the next min date + added the country in the where statement. Apart from that, worked perfectly. Thanks!